# After rewrite Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement giving me fatal error

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal, fatal-error, magento-2.0.7

I have successfully rewrite **Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement** using preference but after enabling paypal express its giving me error like below, on checkout and cart page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\AccountManagement" />
   </config>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 21 passed to
>   Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement, instance of
>   Vendor\Module\Model\AccountManagement given in
>
> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:300\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>
> Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Url),
>   Object(Magento\Tax\Helper\Data),
>   Object(Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data),
>   Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Session), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver),
>   Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\Info), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Url),
>   Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\CartFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\OnepageFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement), Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\Billing\AgreementFactory), Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Type\Fact in
>
> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
>   on line 300, referer:

**EDIT**

My files Constructor

```
 public function __construct(
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Random $mathRandom,
    Validator $validator,
    ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
    AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
    CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
    PsrLogger $logger,
    Encryptor $encryptor,
    ConfigShare $configShare,
    StringHelper $stringHelper,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
    Registry $registry,
    CustomerViewHelper $customerViewHelper,
    DateTime $dateTime,
    CustomerModel $customerModel,
    ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
    ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
) {
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
    $this->validator = $validator;
    $this->validationResultsDataFactory = $validationResultsDataFactory;
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->customerMetadataService = $customerMetadataService;
    $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    $this->configShare = $configShare;
    $this->stringHelper = $stringHelper;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->customerViewHelper = $customerViewHelper;
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
    $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
    $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
    $this->objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
}
```

please suggest me ASAP.

Comment: Please update your Vendor\Module\Model\AccountManagement constructor in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Replace "Vendor" - with your Custom Module Package Name,

 2. Replace "Module" - with your Module Name in :  

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\AccountManagement" />
    </config>
```

Comment: yes, that already i have done and preference is working fine, but when i enable paypal express its giving me error on paypal payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cleanup your temp/cache/generated files and then recompile your codebase (if running in PROD mode)

To cleanup temp/cache/generated files:

```
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/static/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/generated/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/composer_home/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/generation/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/di/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/tmp/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/cache/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/page_cache/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/session/*
```

To Re-Compile your files:

```
cd $MAGENTO_HOME/
$MAGENTO_HOME/bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you continue to see the error message - please post the code for your rewrite class (i.e. `Vendor\Module\Model\AccountManagement`) here for further troubleshooting.